# Rails route not found but shows in rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rake

I am getting the following:

```
Started DELETE "/comments/13115742" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-26 14:37:32 -0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/comments/13115742"):
```

But 'rake routes' clearly shows this route:

```
$ rake routes
comments POST   /comments(.:format)                comments#create {:id=>/0-9+/, :format=>/json|html/}
 comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)            comments#show {:id=>/0-9+/, :format=>/json|html/}
         PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)            comments#update {:id=>/0-9+/, :format=>/json|html/}
         DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)            comments#destroy {:id=>/0-9+/, :format=>/json|html/}
```

And routes.rb clearly has the route defined:

```
resources :comments, :constraints => {:id => /0-9+/, :format => /json|html/}, :except => [:new, :index, :edit]
```

Note that I have a comments controller, and routing from the console doesn't work either:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.8)
irb(main):001:0> r = Rails.application.routes
=> #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007f9ae17b66e0>
irb(main):002:0> r.recognize_path "/comments/3"
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches "/comments/3"
    from /Users/nick/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:633:in `recognize_path'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/nick/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/nick/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/nick/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0> CommentsController.new()
=> #<CommentsController:0x007f9ae3f9d9b0 @_routes=nil, @_action_has_layout=true, @_headers={"Content-Type"=>"text/html"}, @_status=200, @_request=nil, @_response=nil>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `:id` constraint currently is not going to match the numeric string you intend for it to.

Instead of `/0-9+/`, please try `/[0-9]+/` or `/\d+/`

What you have will match something like `/conversations/0-9` or `/conversations/0-9999999`

Comment: But the format is optional (.:format)? Why should it be required? However, even removing that constraint doesn't fix it.

Comment: Also note that the following routes don't resolve either:
`/comments` `/comments.html` `/comments.json` `/comments/3.html` `/comments/3.json`

Comment: I've updated my answer for you *(I actually tested this time in my app :) )*.

Comment: Doh! I stared right at that for far too long without seeing it. Thanks!
For the record the constraint on format is allowed without the defaults.

Comment: Yup, thats why I removed that as part of my answer :) Glad you got it sorted out.